# Trying to return filetype for all users appdata using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am struggling with a PowerShell script to return .json file types in all users %APPDATA% folders. When I run it in ISE, it returns "Get-ChildItem : Access is denied" and when I run ISE as admin, no output is returned.

Here is the script I am working with:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming -Filter '*.json' -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $('.json found in {1}' -f $_.Name, ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)))
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: -Filter doesn't seem to work with a wildcard in the path.  Also, you're missing '{0}' for $_.Name.  You need to be admin to see other users' folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- It is **the use of the `-File` switch that prevents your command from working** - see next section.
- Given that you're filtering by `*.json` and that *directories* are unlikely to match that pattern, you can simply *omit* it.

  - If you do need to guard against that, insert a `Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` pipeline segment after the `Get-ChildItem` call; in PowerShell (Core) 7+, you can simplify to 
    `Where-Object -Not PSIsContainer`

```bash
# Do NOT use -File
# Note: Run from an ELEVATED session (as admin), which is necessary to
#       access other users' directories.
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming -Filter '*.json' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  ForEach-Object { '{0} found in {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.DirectoryName }
```

---

The reason that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-File` doesn't work in your case is that you're combining it with a `-Path` value that is an actual [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) rather than a literal path:

- The wildcard expression is resolved first and - perhaps surprisingly - if *directories* are among the matching paths, they are returned *as themselves*, rather than listing *their children* (what is *inside* them); the latter only happens with *literal* input paths.
- In your case, *only* directories match and the `-File` switch is therefore applied to *them*, not to their children. Since directories don't match the `-File` switch (by definition aren't *files*), there is no output.

  - Whether or not the `-Recurse` switch is also present then makes no difference, given that there's nothing to recurse into.

---

As an aside:

If you wanted to make your command work ***without* `-Recurse`**, **`-File` *can* be made to work, but *only if you append* `\*`** to your input wildcard (the positionally implied `-Path` argument), so as to force enumeration of the *children* to match the `-File` and the `-Filter` against:

```bash
# Without recursion and a trailing /*, -File works
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\* -File -Filter '*.json'
```

However, since PowerShell then needs to enumerate *all* children first, it is then simpler and more efficient to omit `-Filter` and append its pattern directly to the input wildcard:

```bash
# No -Filter, pattern appended to input path
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\*.json -File
```